# IM using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, instant-messaging

Is it possible to create a facebook like kind of chat using signalr? I've seen a few samples but they are all chat rooms. I want to implement a private chat in my site and was wondering if it'd be possible using signalr.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at MessengR https://github.com/davidfowl/MessengR, it's a sample IM thick client using signalr.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the tutorial how to build signalr web chat client http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/01/22/build-a-signal-r-app-part-1.aspx

but basically you want to build something with http://signalr.net/