# Connect web browser with server for communication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, webserver

I am working on a project , client server based live meeting.
I connected two systems in same network. The system is sending mail to each other but cannot join in chat at same time .
I don't know exactly how to configure and connect web browser with server so that it can communicate.
What will be the problem not allowing to chat and please suggest any method to overcome this fault.
In desperate need of help..
Database is connected

Comment: what does this have to do with sql-server?

Comment: Back end is sql server

Answer (score 0):

You could use SignalR as a possible solution. It allows real-time functionality on your web site.

Take a look here: [IM using SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665638/im-using-signalr)